# How to make a template for my custom type?

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have created an custom post type inside functions and added some stuff through ACF in to it.
I tried first to create an archive-forfragningar.php but it didn't work.
Then inside my index.php i added **php if is** but i can not target my custom post type with **is_post_type_archive**. When i go to my archive page i get instead code that is inside else index.php

`my custome post type`

```
function create_forfragningar_cpt() {
  register_post_type( 'forfragningar', 
    array(
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5, // places menu item directly below Posts
      'menu_icon' => '',
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Förfrågningar' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Förfrågning' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Lägg till' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Lägg till nytt Förfrågning' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Redigera' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Redigera Förfrågning' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Nytt Förfrågning' ),
        'view' => __( 'Visa Förfrågning' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Visa Förfrågning' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Sök igenom förfrågningar' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Inga förfrågningar hittade' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Inga förfrågningar hittade i Papperskorgen' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Föräldrer av Förfrågning' ),
        ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_forfragningar_cpt' );
```

`index.php`

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){ ?>

//code

<?php } if ( is_post_type_archive('forfragningar') ) { ?>

<h1>Test</h1>
//code

<?php } else { ?>

//code

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `Then inside my index.php i added php if is but i can not target my custom post type with is_post_type_archive.` And what is your question about? Can you make more specific question?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation.

So i would like to output stuff from my custom post types on my custom post types page.
So that's why i did add <?php } if ( is_post_type_archive('forfragningar') ) { ?> in index.php

But when i look at my custom post types page (www.mydomain.com/forfragningar) i can't see anything but the code that is in <?php } else { ?>.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easy on this way, 
just duplicate `single.php` and rename to `single-custom-post-type-name.php`  like `single-cars.php`, same thing with archive or taxonomy,
`taxonomy-taxonomy-name.php` or `archive-taxonomy-name.php`

Comment: Hello mate.

I did actually try with that in begining but it didn't work. Had to change permalinks to /%category%/%postname% and move an function that had $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); below post type function. Because i did get 404 each time i tried to go to archive or single page. However now it seems like everything works.

Hvala za pomoc. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a specific archive page for custom post type you need to understand [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) works. I also use this [image](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png).

In your case you have to create `archive-forfragningar.php` or `single-forfragningar.php` and insert your code inside these files. [How to make custom post type template.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) Take a look of this also.
You don't need `if ( is_post_type_archive('forfragningar') )` inside your template because wordpress is already to this custom type. You can use `is_post_type_archive('forfragningar')` , in non `forfragningar` custom post type templates file, to check if you are in the query of your custom post type and make a specific work to your case.
 For example the want to render `<h1> tiltle </h1>` to your header in your `forfragningar` page. What you will do is:

insert in your `header.php`

```
if ( is_post_type_archive('forfragningar') ) { ?>

<h1>Test</h1>
//code

<?php } else { ?>

//code

<?php } ?>
```

and then in your custom type template render your header with this `get_header();`
What this will do is create your header for your custom type and your header will run specific code when wordpress runs your `forfragningar` type.

Comment: Hello mate.

I did actually try with that in begining but it didn't work. Had to change permalinks to /%category%/%postname% and move an function that had $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); below post type function. Because i did get 404 each time i tried to go to archive or single page. However now it seems like everything works.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Make php file like `single-{post_type}.php`

Now finally your file name is `single-forfragningar.php`

Make file `single-forfragningar.php` to your root directory

Comment: Hello mate.

I did actually try with that in begining but it didn't work. Had to change permalinks to /%category%/%postname% and move an function that had $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); below post type function. Because i did get 404 each time i tried to go to archive or single page. However now it seems like everything works.

Thanks for help. :)